# What should I do to define my Outlook JS add-in as not compatible with Outlook 2013?

Tags: outlook, office-js

I'm trying to pass AppSource validation process for my Outlook add-in.
Here is  a quote from the validation team recommendation:
"If you do not support 2013 SP1 because you are using an API only available in 2016/Online, you must put these apis in the requirements tag in your manifest."

Well I've placed

```
      <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
```

to the manifest (https://www.ivasoft.com/ShowAliasOWA/showaliasowa.xml).

What else should I do to pass validation if I'm not interested in targeting Outlook 2013?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your manifest in the SellerDashboard you will see the platforms you are required to support.

If you have declared Mailbox 1.5 as the DefaultMinVersion in all relevant locations, then you should not be required to support Outlook 2013 on upload of your manifest.

For more information on host and platform availability please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly select which platforms you would like to allow for your add-in.  Instead you select "requirements" and all platforms that support those requirements are allowed.

I wish you could instead select platforms, but unfortunately that is not the case.